# Windows 7 set environment variable using Cygwin

Tags: windows, windows-7, cygwin, idl-programming-language

I'm trying to use Cygwin to run some astrophysics code called FAST through a program called IDL. In order to do this, I need to set environment variables for the installation path of IDL and the directory of IDL. When I go to the system variables tab in the system settings, I name the variable as appropriate and set the value to C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL85, but I get an error saying that

```
    STUDENT@SES-6TTJK72 /cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Downloads/FAST_v1.0/FAST_v1.0/example_phot 
$ ../fast
../fast C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL85 .:+C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL85/lib
../fast: line 6: C:\Program: command not found
```

Now this seems to be happening because Cygwin can't read the space in Program Files as space is used to delimit the arguments, but I've tried every solution I can think of to get around this. I've tried Program\ Files, I've tried quotes around the whole thing, etc. I was just wondering if there was some way to set the windows environment variables in Cygwin itself so I can just type the path out in the notation that Cygwin uses and it would be able to understand it for sure. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: how are you escaping  the argument ?

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry but I'm very new to this stuff.

Comment: What character are you using to escape the command or the arguments. You show nothing. eg `../fast 'C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL85' '.:+C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL85/lib' `

Comment: All I typed was ../fast, the rest of the code is what it printed out.

Comment: So `C:\Program Files\Exelis\IDL85'` is in the PATH ? How you set it ?

Comment: IDL_PATH is an environment variable I created in Windows by going to System->Advanced Settings->Environment Variables

Comment: Have you tried instead to follow the instruction from fast itself  ? `source /IDL_INSTALLATION_PATH/bin/idl_setup.bash` where IDL_INSTALLATION_PATH is 'cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Exelis/IDL85'

Comment: The problem is there is no idl_setup.bash because it's the Windows version of IDL (at least that's how I understand it).

Comment: What if you made a symbolic link pointing to the Program Files directory? You could name the link so that it has no spaces, and then set that as the IDL_PATH environment variable...? That would at least test your theory that it's failing because of the space in "Program Files".